# Why is bundler installing on my app/path directory? How to change it back to default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, bundler, rbenv

I on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine and is working on a rails app. After reinstalling bundler and then running `bundle install` bundler now creates a /path folder where it dumps all the installed gems.

I think this used to store the files on some other folders on the system since I have never seen git detect his folder, now its in the app directory.

Any help?

Edit: My ruby is with rbenv.

Comment: how the way you installed Ruby? using RVM or RBenv

Comment: Its with rbenv @SaiqulHaq. Updated my question.